# Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS broken menus

Tags: lubuntu, themes

My menus in Lubuntu are broken... This only happens when i change the window border theme to something else than the default. I tried changing back to the default theme but the problem still exists! Does anyone know if there's a way to fix it without re-installing lubuntu?
Thanks in advance!

Screenshot of the volume control app:

[image: Screenshot of the volume control app]

Comment: Which apps display this problem and which don't? What chip do you have and which driver are you using?

Comment: I installed ubuntu so i'm ok now. Thanks a lot for replying though!

Comment: There are others with this issue but I cannot reproduce it. I'm thinking it must have something to do with particular hardware, so if you could answer at least the latter questions, that would be great. For anyone else with the problem, see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openbox/+bug/1793254